# Unable to fetch database values in RemoteView

Tags: android, android-appwidget

Well I wanted to make an AppWidget, I define the layouts,info for app widget, a broadcast receiver and a service to handle AppWidget.

```
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this
            .getApplicationContext());
    int[] allWidgetIds = intent
            .getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(),
            SmsSchedulerWidget.class);

    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext()
            .getPackageName(), R.layout.schdulesms_appwidget_layout);

    DatabaseManager dbManager = new DatabaseManager(context.getApplicationContext());
    dbManager.open();
    String contactNumber = dbManager.fetchContactNumber();
    String date = dbManager.fetchDate();
    String message = dbManager.fetchMessage();
    String status = dbManager.fetchStatus();

    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.to_appwidget_saved_data, contactNumber);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.date_appwidget_saved_data, date);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_appwidget_saved, message);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.message_appwidgset_saved_data, status);

    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```

This is my code.............

But in other activities i can easily retrieve database values without any null pointer exception. Please if anybody could point out whats wrong with my code than i will be higly grateful................

The log cat errors are:

03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.android.braindigit.schedulesms.appWidgetService@4053da30 with Intent { cmp=com.android.braindigit.schedulesms/.appWidgetService (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2052)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:994)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:118)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at com.android.braindigit.schedulesms.DatabaseManager.open(DatabaseManager.java:36)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at com.android.braindigit.schedulesms.appWidgetService.onStart(appWidgetService.java:41)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at android.app.Service.onStartCommand(Service.java:428)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2039)
03-02 17:26:32.174: E/AndroidRuntime(32265):    ... 10 more

Comment: something is null somewhere. by looking closely at the logcat, you may find the line number, and with some luck determine the object that is not properly initialized. By sharing this information, someone might be able to help you

Comment: the whole giberish thingy around the NullPointerException mention. All that is in red in your logcat. The 2O-odd lines surrounding the error

Comment: Your problem lies in `com.android.braindigit.schedulesms.DatabaseManager.open()`, as indicated by the stack trace. Also, get rid of all references to `getApplicationContext()` unless you know **exactly and specifically why you are using it**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I dont know how genuine it is to answer my own question but i thought it would help other people if they have the same problem as me.....So, after banging my head for hours, finally i realised that i was passing a null context.So, i did the following things and it worked....

from the broadcase receiver I passed the following intents to my service:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),appWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS,allWidgetIds);
    intent.putExtra("contactNumber", contactNumber);
    intent.putExtra("date", date);
    intent.putExtra("message",message);
    intent.putExtra("status", status);
    //update the widgets via the service
```

and in service i did the following things:

```
    String contactNumber = intent.getStringExtra("contactNumber");
    String date = intent.getStringExtra("date");
    String message =intent.getStringExtra("message");
    String status = intent.getStringExtra("status");


    for (int widgetId : allWidgetIds) {
        RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(this
                .getApplicationContext().getPackageName(),
                R.layout.schdulesms_appwidget_layout);



        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.to_appwidget_saved_data,
                contactNumber);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.date_appwidget_saved_data, date);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.status_appwidget_saved, message);
        remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.message_appwidgset_saved_data,
                status);

        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(thisWidget, remoteViews);
```